# Ускорение миграции/изменения таблиц в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

поделитесь пожалуйста мыслями, опытом.

Хочется улучшить/ускорить миграцию MySQL базы данных.
У нас стандартный подход, скрипты в liquibase, выкатывается новая версия, скрипты запускаются.

Но продуктивная БД достаточно большая и изменение таблицы(добавление колонки, изменение значений) с 10-15 миллионами записей может длится часами. Что призводит к блокировке таблицы и так д.. Поэтому деплой с изменениями стараются делать когда не слишком много запросов и так д..
Хотя имеется достаточно продуктивный Galera Cluster.

Как можно улучшить сию ситуацию?
Как делаете миграции вы? Как решали такую проблему?
Где почитать о улучшениях при миграции/изменении БД?
Решит ли частично проблемы переезд с MySQL на PostreSQL?

Спасибо!

Comment: У нас например табличка в 300млн... Простои недопустимы... Так что при изменении структуры приходится специальным внешним скриптом создавать новую таблицу без индексов (кроме primary). На основную вешать триггера, логирующие какие записи менялись. Копировать данные (именно внешним скриптом, что бы не было insert select). Копировать измененные строки (по логам созданным триггером). Создавать индексы. Опять копировать то что за это время изменилось. Копировать изменения за время копирования, пару раз. Переименовывать таблицы. копировать остатки.

Comment: И да, при последней миграции добавил в таблицу несколько пустых колонок с разными типами данных. Уже пару раз спасали. Просто колонку переименовываю и все.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за комментарий. Интересная идея с дополнительными колонками (про запас).